# Move sidebarMenu to top when header is disabled in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to have the header disabled in my shinydashboard, and I want the first item in the menu on the sidebar to be placed at the absolute top of the sidebar, where it by default is placed a little lower.
Is there a way to move it up there?

```r
ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
  shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
  shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("house"))
  )),
  shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
    shinydashboard::tabBox(
      title = "title",
      shiny::tabPanel(
        "test panel"
        )
      )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(
    shinydashboard::dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
    shinydashboard::dashboardSidebar(
        tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar {padding-top: 0px !important;}")),
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("house"))
        )
    ),
    shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
        shinydashboard::tabBox(
            title = "title",
            shiny::tabPanel(
                "test panel"
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Running this app, produces:

[image]

Check if this is what you wanted?

Comment: Excellent, thanks!
Is there a way to remove the footer as well?